# bootstrap 3: Aligning badges in a list

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a list with badges like this:

```
<ul class="list-group ticketView">
    <li class="list-group-item ticketView">
        <span class="badge pull-left">dkf</span>
        skdjflksdf
    </li>...
```

Here is what is looks like:
[image]

I know I can calculate the right padding for each badge with js, but I was wondering if bootstrap had a way to align the badges and text so that they are even (like two columns).

edit---
As per  webeno this was trivially simple:

```
span.badge.pull-left {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

As long as I make sure the text isn't too long this works perfectly.

Comment: what about explicitly setting their widths (or min-width)...? i might be wrong, but i don't think you'll be able to calculate the width/padding with pure CSS...

Comment: ...alternatively you could use tables instead...

Comment: Oh man sooo easy. I was thinking about how to do that, but for some reason it never occurred to me its as simple as setting it on the span's styles. All update my post

Comment: If you post that as an answer I will except it.

Comment: Seems to work well when removing the specific width: http://www.bootply.com/125233

Comment: Weird, so it should just work the way I want by default? what could be causing it to do what its doing in the screenshot?

Comment: @Skelly, haha, all your first ones are actually the same, so no wonder they will be the same in each row :)

Comment: @user1028270 I tried with tables, have a look at my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this could be achieved by using tables instead of list items, and setting `.list-group-item`'s display property to `inherit` (by default it uses `display:block`).

So in your custom CSS file you could add this:

```
.list-group-item
{
    display:inherit
}
```

Your table structure could look something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<table class="list-group ticketView">
    <tbody><tr class="list-group-item ticketView">
      <td class="badge pull-left">dkdsdcf</td>
      <td>skd</td>
      <td>ef</td>
      <td>wef</td>
      <td>ejflksdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list-group-item ticketView">
      <td class="badge pull-left">dk</td>
      <td>skdssd</td>
      <td>efasdasd</td>
      <td>wefdasdasdasd</td>
      <td>ejff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="list-group-item ticketView">
      <td class="badge pull-left">dkfsdsdcsdcs</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>ef</td>
      <td>w</td>
      <td>ejfasasdasdadf</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

**[Bootply demo here](http://www.bootply.com/125244)**

Answer (score 1):

Please check the solution below,

```
<ul class="list-group ticketView">
<li class="list-group-item ticketView">
    <span class="badge pull-left">dkf</span>
     <span class="title">skdjflksdf</span>

</li>
<li class="list-group-item ticketView">
    <span class="badge pull-left">aaaaa</span>
     <span class="title">aaa</span>
</li>
```

```
    ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

[JSFiddle for test](http://jsfiddle.net/RT9WL/25/)

Comment: this only works if you have 2, if I understand well the OP wants this to work with 3 or more...?

Comment: i meant more than 2 in one row... but it might not be what the OP wants, not sure...

Comment: If he wants to have multiple column, then its not wise to use list for it. Preferably should go with Grid. thats more manageable component. what you say?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use CSS rules and modified your HTML:

HMTL:

```
<ul class="list-group ticketView">
    <li class="list-group-item ticketView">
        <span class="badge pull-left">dkf</span>
        <span class="badge-title">skdjflksdf</span>
    </li>...
```

CSS:

```
.ist-group li { clear:both; display:block; }
.ist-group li span.badge {float: left;}
.ist-group li span.badge-title {float: right;}
```

I have not tested this code, it is only to see how they can do.

Comment: erm... not sure how that would answer the OP's question... you're merely doing floating, this won't set the padding or width... by the way, bootstrap `pull-left` is equivalent to `float: left`...

Comment: To be fair, it's not entirely clear what the OP is asking for.

Comment: I give you that @Paulie_D!

Answer (score -1):

“edit--- As per webeno this was trivially simple”…

```
span.badge.pull-left {
 margin-right: 10px;
 width: 100px;
 }
```

This worked for me. It is easier to understand visually, **so I have created a screenshot** comparing 3 ways of doing this: old fashioned table, regular list group (the problem), and list group using the “pull-left” technique described by webeno. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4PBp.jpg]

Hope this is helpful to anyone having trouble.